# KDB: Union of time intervals

Tags: union, kdb

Any nifty ways of converting a series of (possibly overlapping) time intervals into a set of disjoint time intervals covering the same times?

Example:
interval1:(07:00:00;08:00:00)
interval2:(07:30:00;08:30:00)
interval3:(10:00:00;11:00:00)

Desired output:
((07:00:00;08:30:00) ; (10:00:00;11:00:00))

Answer (score 1):

In a table context you can do something like:

```
q)d:([]st:07:00:00 07:30:00 10:00:00; et:08:00:00 08:30:00 11:00:00)
q)d
st       et
-----------------
07:00:00 08:00:00
07:30:00 08:30:00
10:00:00 11:00:00

distinct update st:?[st<prev et;prev st;st], et:et^?[et>next st;next et;et] from d

st       et
-----------------
07:00:00 08:30:00
10:00:00 11:00:00
```

Not sure if i'd call it nifty, but it's decent!

Comment: Here's that solution extracted as a function: `{distinct flip{(?[x<prev y;prev x;x];?[y>next x;y^next y;y])}. flip x}`. It could also be expressed as `{{distinct flip((x<prev y)xprev x;y^(neg y>next x)xprev y)}. flip x}`.